How to view public (shared) calendars in Salesforce Mobile app?
I've researched a lot about this and found out that Salesforce mobile doesn't support public calendars.
Are there are any (hopefully free) third-party apps on appexchange which support this?
Or can we achieve this with custom code?
Can someone please guide me in the right direction?

You could make a flow that makes copies of the calendar for as many people as will view it, and then make them the owners of those calendars. Then it can be a private calendar, as long as the person running the flow is an admin.
You can make an automatic flow that can be triggered by any user that updates the master calendar.

I actually have that in place and it's working as expected on Desktop. The issue is with the Mobile, the Calendar in Mobile app ONLY shows My Events calendar. There's no settings to show/choose Public calendars in Mobile.
